# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS unable to access Wifi

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, 20.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in my laptop, every time, when I turn on the laptop,
the Wifi option is disabled.
In order to enable it, I've had to run the below command and restart my laptop (everytime).

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Is there any way, to make Ubuntu automatically detect Wifi, without having to restart the `network-manager`?

I've disabled Secure boot,
I was unable to connect to Wifi, when I was installing Ubuntu.
I'm dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10

Please let me know, if you guys know, a permanent fix for this problem,

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`
output:

`cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory`

`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`
output:

```
network:
  renderer: NetworkManager
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManage
```

`sudo lshw -C network`
output:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: b0:6e:bf:ab:d5:4e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df304000-df304fff memory:df300000-df303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 78
       serial: 00:e1:8c:42:0f:18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=36.77d01142.0 ip=192.168.1.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:df100000-df101fff
```

`lshw`
output:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: b0:6e:bf:ab:d5:4e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df304000-df304fff memory:df300000-df303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 78
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df100000-df101fff
```

Comment: Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Disable Fast Start feature in Windows.

Comment: @Pilot6, I also tried disabling the Fast start.

Comment: This issue, occurs when I switch to Windows and then switch back to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your /etc/netplan/*.yaml... keeping the exact same indentation, spacing, and no tabs...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/*.yaml` # use the correct .yaml file name

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
#
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then go to the NetworkManager applet at the right side of the top panel and select your wifi network.

**Update #1:**

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: I updated the .yaml file, and restarted the laptop, I was able to use the wifi in the applet,
but when I switch to Windows and switch back to Ubuntu, the wifi option is gone again.

Comment: You did the `sudo netplan` commands, yes? Boot to the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, and boot to the oldest kernel that's showing. You have -42 now. Show me the `lshw` command again, when the wifi is not working.

Comment: I did ```sudo netplan``` command, I've added the ```lshw``` command output (when the wifi option is not visible) in the question.

Comment: Did you boot to the older kernel? If so, is the wifi showing there? Rather than use the `lshw` command by itself, please show me `sudo lshw -C network` again when the wifi is not working.

Comment: the system fails to load when I run older kernel (-26), 
it stops at ```Starting modem manager ...```            
and I've updated the question, with latest ```sudo lshw -C network`` command output
for 42 kernel.

Comment: @chqdrian Very strange. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your laptop.

Comment: ```Asus FX503VD.308  
Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8 
GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 / GeForce GTX 1050/P  
OS type - 64-bit```

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 20.04 before (without dual booting Windows) few days back, there was no issues.
But, for personal reasons, I had to install again Windows(dual boot), that's when I started facing issues. If I used only Ubuntu continuously (without booting Windows), the Wifi is working fine, only when I login into Windows and login into Ubuntu, the wifi issue occurs, it's like it's reverting back to previous state.
I've created 4 partitions of my 1TB hard disk, 1 partition for Windows, 1 partition for Ubuntu and 2 common drives

Comment: @chqdrian Your BIOS is current. Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: I followed your instructions, now I'm able to access my wifi, (even after switching to windows.) If I could double upvote your answer, I would. Thanks @heynnema

Comment: @chqdrian Great news! Thanks for the feedback.