# Wifi driver missing after Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS clean install on HP laptop

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

```
$ lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 38:22:e2:e7:80:06
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:51 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fce04000-fce04fff memory:fce00000-fce03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcd00000-fcd0ffff
```

Cable network is sound, wireless is "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".
Suspicious bits are "*-network UNCLAIMED", and no driver under wireless configuration. Also there's no driver for ubuntu at realtek web page (https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8821ce-software).

The laptop originally had Windows 10 on it, and wifi was working fine.

The answer to [Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS unable to access Wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265042/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-unable-to-access-wifi) didn't help.

Where can I get the driver for this, and how to configure the adapter to use it?

Comment: Thank you tremendously. While the answer you shared seems to be obsolete, it led to more recent solution that worked perfectly: https://askubuntu.com/a/1162258/1117612. Writing this answer over wireless already :) Cheers!